# Javascript: Merging a dynamic object's value into another object's array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In React/Redux, I have a dynamic object (action.payload):

```
{
  cars: "Ferrari"
}
```

which I need to combine to a nested object (redux):

```
{
  filters: {
    ships: ['Star'],
    cars: ['Ford']
    airplanes: ['Boeing']
  }
}
```

I tried this but it seems this is merging with 'filters' still being maintained:

```
return {
  ...state,
  filters: Object.assign({}, state.filters, action.payload)
}
```

I am expecting the arrays to merge and get something like:

```
{
  filters: {
    ships: ['Star'],
    cars: ['Ford', 'Ferrari']
    airplanes: ['Boeing']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
return{
...state,
filters: {...state.filters, 
cars: [...state.filters.cars, action.payload.cars], 
ships: [...state.filters.ships, action.payload.ships], 
airplanes: [...state.filters.airplanes, action.payload.airplanes]}
 }
```

Comment: the 'car' is dynamic as well. which means that the application might pass either 'cars', 'ships' or 'airplanes'

Comment: Can you change the payload to use arrays instead and ensure that the unused ones are empty arrays first? If so you can use [...state.filters.cars, ...action.payload.cars] etc.